# How to execute WebClient?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I try to execute WebClient, but I get an error.

I have tested directly in the browser if the PHP form works, and it's fine.

```
http://localhost/CreateContact.php?Name=Abc&Number=123
```

I am running Apache24 and PHP7.3.5

In *php.ini* I load the extensions below:

```
extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64
extension = php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64
```

So it is Thread safe.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/CreateContact.php");
NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
parameters.Add("Name", "Abc");
parameters.Add("Number", "123");
client.UploadValuesCompleted += client_UploadValuesCompleted;
client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, "POST", parameters);

enter code here
```

The app stops on my Android. The shown error is:

```
05-24 18:57:38.045 E/mono-rt (27754): 71c6a000-71c6d000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 5913                               /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.art
05-24 18:57:38.045 E/mono-rt (27754): 71c6d000-71c6e000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 5353                               /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-oneplus_sdk_utils.art
05-24 18:57:38.045 E/mono-rt (27754): 71c6e000-71c6f000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 4844                               /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-oneplus_sdk_wrapper.art
05-24 18:57:38.045 E/mono-rt (27754): 71c6f000-71c70000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 2949                               /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-tcmiface.art
05-24 18:57:38.045 E/mono-rt (27754): 71c70000-71c72000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 2224                               /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-telephony-ext.art
05-24 18:57:38.045 E/mono-rt (27754): 71c72000-71c78000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 197160                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-WfdCommon.art
05-24 18:57:38.045 E/mono-rt (27754): 71c78000-71c79000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 197091                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-oem-services.art
05-24 18:57:38.045 E/mono-rt (27754): 71c79000-71c7e000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 193760                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-qcom.fmradio.art
05-24 18:57:38.046 E/mono-rt (27754): 71c7e000-71c85000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 188449                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-qcnvitems.art
05-24 18:57:38.047 F/libc    (27754): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x20 in tid 28958 (Thread Pool Wor)
```

Please help. Any suggestions? Thanks very much.

Comment: have you tested the form in the Android browser?

Comment: Just to clarify - you run Apache server on your Android device, right?

Comment: When using `localhost` on the device|emulator you are referring to the device|emulator itself, not the actual  server(PC) that is hosting your web service.

Comment: I run Apache server on my computer. So yes, I realize now, I can't run my Android app from my Android phone, because I can't access localhost and I don't have access to the router to do port forward. Thanks, guys. Guess there is no other way around to access local host (127.0.0.1) from my phone.

Comment: have you tried just using the IP of the apache server?  I'm assuming both devices are on the same network

Comment: Just figured out to use the local intranet IP instead of localhost. It works! Thank you.